# Are pipes in each process independent?

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe

If I generate multiple `subprocess.Popen(['commands', 'that', 'I', 'called'])` and for each I do `stdin.write(..)` or `p.communicate(...)`to interact with the commands, is it guarantee to be independent and will come back to the each process (stdout from the called command)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do this:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(
    cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, _ = proc.communicate()
```

You will get a separate set of pipes for each process.  The value `subprocess.PIPE` is just a special flag to tell `subprocess.Popen()` to create a new pipe -- so the above command creates two new pipes: one pipe for `stdin` and a separate pipe for `stdout`.

If you do this:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
proc.wait()
```

The new process will share `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` with your process (well, basically -- the kernel side will be shared).

Comment: Thanks. I ask Aakash below the same question. Given a web app with multiple users. I need to issue the same command for each user. So by setting `stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE`, I am guarantee to have independent communication with each new process (write and read back-and-forth)?

Comment: @User007: Yes, that will give you independent pipes for each process.

Comment: Thanks. I will test it out. I don't really want to jump into the OS land blindly. Sometimes it's a little helpful to get reassurance first. I always set the `PIPE` myself.

Comment: I am not very sure about python, but in case of multiple pipes, you can close the read end of the first pipe and set it to stdin, and for the last pipe you dont have to close the stdout.

Comment: @AakashAnuj: Again, this is all handled by the `subprocess` library in Python.  You don't need to manage pipes yourself because the library does it for you.

Comment: @AakashAnuj: If you are "not very sure about Python", perhaps you shouldn't answer questions about Python libraries.  The `subprocess` module in Python has no close equivalent in C.

Comment: @DietrichEpp It is just that I tried to help ! I clearly mentioned that i took C into consideration !

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about python, but as far as C is concerned, pipe is not independent for each process.

Pipes are for the sole pupose of communicating between the parent and the child processes or even between the child processes themselves.

The data written in a pipe by a particular process can be read by another process from the read end of the pipe.

Comment: Thanks. Correct me if I am wrong. If we calls the command   via `subprocess`, it should generate a new process. I am guessing what you are saying is that since the person (processes) issuing the same command is ONE individual person, so if two processes returns `stdout`, the person may get a mixed stdout. That's where the problem lies, right? Alternative?

Comment: You will have to close the write end of one of the pipes, so that one of them dies not write to stdout. If it helped you, plz do upvote :)

Comment: @AakashAnuj: The Python `subprocess` module will handle the pipes automatically based on flags passed to it.  I don't think C is really relevant here, since this is a question about the behavior of a Python library.

Comment: Well, it helps to understand from the C perspective. But I will come back later after experiment. Thanks.